# Cmd : ] was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have written a program called promptvar.bat.
Everytime I run it normally, it just says:

> ] was unexpected at this time.

What is the problem? Is it at `::`? Or is it at `echo`?
This is the code: (*SYNTAX INCLUDED*)

```
@echo off

::SYNTAX:
::PROMPTVAR [ /? | [VARIABLE NAME] [PROMPT] ([NEWLINE]) ]

::CHECK /?
if "%1"=="/?" (
echo PROMPTVAR
echo.
echo GET USER INPUT.
echo.
echo SYNTAX:
echo PROMPTVAR [ /? | [VARIABLE NAME] [PROMPT TEXT] ([NEWLINE]) ]
echo.
echo./? : GET HELP INFORMATION - THIS IS IT!
echo VARIABLE NAME : NAME OF VARIABLE
echo PROMPT TEXT : TEXT FOR TIP / PROMPT
echo NEWLINE : WITH THIS PARAMETER, YOU CAN MAKE A NEW LINE TO GET INPUT.
echo.
goto :EOF
)

::REAL INFO
if "%3"=="NEWLINE" (
echo.%2
set /p %1=
goto :EOF
) ELSE (
set /p %1="%2"
goto :EOF
)
goto :EOF

::LOCASE ONLY
:LoCase
FOR %%i IN ("A=a" "B=b" "C=c" "D=d" "E=e" "F=f" "G=g" "H=h" "I=i" "J=j" "K=k" "L=l" "M=m" "N=n" "O=o" "P=p" "Q=q" "R=r" "S=s" "T=t" "U=u" "V=v" "W=w" "X=x" "Y=y" "Z=z") DO CALL SET "%1=%%%1:%%~i%%"
GOTO:EOF
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Any second now someone will be along who's spotted the exact place there the problem is, and they will tell you.   But I dunno if you will learn much that way.   Honestly: have you stripped this back to find out which line is causing it?   That's the way you find out what's going wrong for yourself...

Comment: :: is not a comment: it is a label.  If you want a comment, use rem.  It is not as pretty as :: but it may stop you from getting the errors that you are getting.

Comment: If you rem out @echo off, you will find out exactly what it is complaining about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
echo PROMPTVAR [ /? | [VARIABLE NAME] [PROMPT TEXT] ([NEWLINE]) ]
```

Because this is itself in an `if`, cmd needs to know that the <kbd>)</kbd> is not the close of the `if "%1"=="/?" (`

To do this, escape the <kbd>)</kbd> with a caret <kbd>^</kbd> Thus:

```
echo PROMPTVAR [ /? | [VARIABLE NAME] [PROMPT TEXT] ([NEWLINE]^) ]
```

---

Demonstration of `%%` and `%hi%`

Batch:

```
::@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "hi="

ECHO +%%+%hi%+
goto :EOF
```

Results:

```
c:\106x>SETLOCAL

c:\106x>SET "hi=" 

c:\106x>ECHO +%++ 
+%++

c:\106x>goto :EOF
```

Note that `echo` is *ON* so each line is interpreted and displayed after the prompt.

`+` use to delineate the two elements displayed.

Seems to work my way for me - what batch are you testing to have this work as you appear to claim?

Comment: I think, also the pipe `|`?

Comment: Certainly, if you wish to use the pipe literally. The caret "escapes" (ie turns off) the special meaning of the following character - except for `%`. To escape `%`, you need to double it (`%%`)